# How to reduce distance between widgets and window size with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

What I currently have:

[image: Current window]

What I want:

[image: Wanted window]

For those unable to view the images; the widgets are spread out by some sort of margin between them. I would like to keep them as close as possible. How can I squeeze the widgets closer together?

I have already tried:
`setFixedSize(sizeHint());` and `setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);` on the main window, layouts, and widget object. Nothing seems to work.

As an extra, I would also appreciate this:
(having the label get even closer to the lineEdit)
[image]

I am using Windows and Qt 5.11.1, 64-bits.
The window constructor code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
    widget = new QWidget();
    label = new QLabel(tr("Enter your name:"));
    nameLine = new QLineEdit;
    nameLine->setMinimumWidth(250);
    label->setBuddy(nameLine);

    okButton = new QPushButton (tr("Ok"));
    clearButton = new QPushButton (tr("Clear"));

    connect(okButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(message()));
    connect(clearButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(clear()));

    QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout;
    grid->addWidget(label,0,0);
    grid->addWidget(nameLine,1,0);
    grid->addWidget(okButton,0,1);
    grid->addWidget(clearButton,1,1);

    widget->setLayout(grid);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Leo v0.0"));
    setCentralWidget(widget);
}
```

Comment: show code as text

Comment: Sorry, I changed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is to establish a `QVBoxLayout` with `addStretch()`:

```
QVBoxLayout *vlay = new QVBoxLayout;
QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout;
grid->addWidget(label, 0, 0);
grid->addWidget(nameLine, 1, 0);
grid->addWidget(okButton, 0, 1);
grid->addWidget(clearButton, 1, 1);
vlay->addLayout(grid);
vlay->addStretch();
widget->setLayout(vlay);
setCentralWidget(widget);
```

Comment: That does solve the problem of the margin between the widgets, even without the stretch. However, the main window stills not at its minum.

Comment: @Werneck 
Do you want a fixed size that is the minimum in the window or do you want to set the minimum size in the window at the beginning and then the user can change the size? 
On the other hand I recommend you to respond promptly.

Comment: @Werneck use `setFixedSize(sizeHint())` or `resize(sizeHint())` after `setCentralWidget(...)`

Comment: I'm not able to respond that fast, I'm at work. Also, this is just a simple test program I've made. It just annoyed me that the window has all this useless space. I want it to be resizable, if the user so much wants it, not fixed size. I already tried using 'setFixedSize(sizeHint())', but not after setting the central widget. I'll give this and 'resize(sizeHint())' a try. Thanks for the help! =D

Comment: "do you want to set the minimum size in the window at the beginning and then the user can change the size?" -> THIS!   =P

Comment: @Werneck then use `resize(sizeHint())` after `setCentralWidget(...)`